# XAML with inline JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wpf, xaml

Is it possible to insert JavaScript code into XAML?

Comment: Why do you want to insert javascript in WPF application? Can you provide more info on this?

Comment: I wanted to use a simple but flexible langauge with XAML - so that a user could enter simple functions for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IronPython or IronRuby with WPF or Silverlight. Here is one article on [WPF with IronPython](http://remark.wordpress.com/2009/01/27/an-introduction-to-wpf-with-ironpython/) and another article of [WPF with IronRuby](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WPFSampleInIronRubyTalkingViaCToWesabe.aspx).

As for Javascript, there is work on [IronJS](http://github.com/fholm/IronJS) as well as [Jint](http://jint.codeplex.com/) which you should be able to use in WPF similar to how IronPython and IronRuby are used. I haven't seen any articles on WPF with IronJS/Jint yet, but in theory it should be very similar to the other DLR implementations.